# How do I expand a window to show more content in cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm building an application in Cocoa and I want to be able to let the user click a button, which expands the window size showing content that was previously hidden.

For example, the top 68 pixels of my application show a summary of what is happening (like syncing data to a server) and there's a button off to the right that when clicked expands the window down and let's the user enter more information.

Problems I'm having are.

1) the background image I setup by subclassing NSImageView seems to be originated at the bottom left corner instead of the top left, so my button which should be over the right corner a the top of the background starts off over the right corner at the bottom of the background.

2) The window expands down and the button floats up. So the button starts at the bottom right corner and ends up at the top right corner. I want it to be in the top right corner always.

I think all of this would be solved if I could figure out how to tell the window to start at the top left corner and grow down, but not move controls around, simply hide them if the window isnt big enough.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question right then this should be it:

1) it is so because the coordinate system on mac is with the origin on bottom left. I think you should just move your image view up a little when you're resizing.

2) When you expand the window the buttons frame is based with the origin on the bottom left corner so again you will need to offset it when the view grows.

I think that by using auto layout and setting up the proper constraints things might be a little easier :)